# QuickBlox, Push notification not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

I am developing an iOS app with QuickBlox backend service.
In that push notification is not working anymore. I did following,

1. Uploaded both production and sandbox certificate in admin panel
2. Subscribed for push notification in the app by the code

   [QBMessages TRegisterSubscriptionWithDelegate:self];
3. Send the push notification from both admin panel and the app by the code

   ```
       [QBMessages TSendPushWithText:mesage 
                        toUsers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", userID] 
                       delegate:self];
   ```

Even tried with QuickBlox sample project "SimpleSample Messages" by following the procedure mentioned in their tutorial video. It is not working in that project itself.

Also, I have validated the certificates by this application "https://github.com/blommegard/APNS-Pusher". It is working exactly.

But not working any more in QuickBlox. I am stuck on this now.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the push notification.

The issue is in my push certificate. When we created the certificate again, we are able to get the Push certification successfully.

Thanks!